# “one down, three to go”

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Marcia Howard, a former teacher and organizer who can be found at the square nearly every day, led the crowd in chanting Floyd's name and **“one down, three to go,”** in reference to the other officers charged in Floyd's death. Behind her, a calendar hanging on a gas pump at the Speedway is marked with the date Thomas Lane, J. Kueng and Tou Thao will be arraigned.

Source: [USAToday](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2021/06/25/chauvin-sentencing-george-floyd-square-mixed-emotions/5344967001/)

I couldn't feel the power of the slogan "one down, three to go" but simply understand it as "one criminal has been sentenced, three others will be sentenced too."  Am I on the right track?

Lacking sensitivity to the English slogan appears to be a regret to me. Does this slogan sound contemptible (towards the criminals)? Or does it sound powerful to uphold the law? I have no clue at all.

Comment: The sense is "One of our targets has been achieved, there are three more to go". I think you mean _contemptuous_ rather than _contemptible_.

Comment: @Benjamin Harman the linked article is basically descriptive. It is surely not a 'far-right" piece. If it takes any position at all, it would be slightly left of center. In any case this seems to be a legitimate question and should not be flagged IMO.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - while USA Today is hardly a bastion of progressive thought, it isn't exactly far-right either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression '[first number] down, [second number] to go' simply expresses that a step has been completed in a sequence. In the context you provided, one criminal out of four has been convicted, and the remaining three still need to be convicted. We generally use the expression about situations where completion is desired.

Comment: Thank you.  Here's a scenario in which "one down, three to go" is used. I wonder whether the expression is used correctly:  The teacher told the class to complete reading 4 books in one week. Five days passed one of the students inquired the rest of the classmates: "Have you completed reading the books?" They cried out "one down, three to go", meaning that most of them only finished reading one book and three books left unread, the teacher's assigned task appeared to be "mission impossible."

Comment: A more typical use of the expression would be for a student to say it after finishing the first book and before starting on the second. The sense is 'That's one stage completed!' rather than 'The whole task is impossible'.